# illegal token when using data from res.json using Node and Express 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

I've created a simple bookmarks service for myself with a REST api built in Node using Express 4:

```
res.json(200, output); // output is an object
```

Using POSTman I've tested the api fully and all is working. I'm now trying to load the data with jQuery's $.post function:

```
$.post( "http://my.uri.com/v1/endpoint").done(function(data){
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        var table_row;
        data.bookmarks.forEach(function(bm){                    
        console.log(bm);
        console.log(bm.title);
            console.log(bm.dstamp);
            table_row = "<tr><td>"+ bm.dstamp +"</td></tr>";
       });
    } else {
       console.error('There was a problem');
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The console.log calls work just fine and I see the data I expect:

```
Object {id: 16, uri: "http://www.alaskapublic.org/kska/", title: "KSKA | Alaska Public Media", tags: "radio, npr, alaska", dstamp: 1401206372}
KSKA | Alaska Public Media
1401206372
```

It's when I try to use one of the object properties that I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

This is caused by the line:

```
table_row = "<tr><td>"+ bm.dstamp +"</td></tr>";
```

It doesn't seem to matter if the property I'm using is a number or a string. I've tried setting the content header in Express but since POSTman and console.log() are happy without it I don't think it's the problem. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
FireFox dev tools report the error as:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

Comment: Are there any invisible characters in the `table_row = "<tr><td>"+ bm.dstamp +"</td></tr>";` line? That could cause JS to throw that error.

Comment: Not that I can see. Neither of the consoles in Chrome or FireFox show any, nor does the POSTman response. It even happens with the 'id' which is an integer generated by the database.

Comment: So, if you comment that line out, it works?

Comment: Yep. Any attempt to use the property as part of a string fails. If I try to parse as a string using String() I get the same error.

Comment: Can you remove that line, and the one above / below it, and re-type them manually? Just to make sure there are absolutely no illegal characters in there anywhere.

Comment: That seems to have worked! Very strange. Many thanks.

Comment: @Cebrus How do I close this and attribute the solution to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably some kind of illegal (invisible) character in the line the error is pointing at.

Select that line along with the lines above and below it, delete them, and type them over again, manually. That should get rid of the invisible characters.